# Which data structure should I use for this particular problem?

Tags: c#, oracle, data-structures

I need help in determing the data structure for this problem. The data is we have type and sub-type and mostly sub-type is null, but for very few types, sub-type has a value. I need to read the data from source tables which is available in another table. Which data structure I can use on the application to store all this information? The application has no information about the Type_id. its only for the database. So we should save Type, SubType, Source Table in the data structure.
[image]

Comment: Are you asking for the data structure, or the class structure?

Comment: I don't want to use class because I am trying to make it configuratble. i.e. we should be able to add a new column in the type table and the application should pickup the new column. I have to store all these values in the Application cache. So whenever the application request source table for the particular combination of type and sub type I should be able to retrieve it from the data structure. I thought of using 2 dictionaries. I for type and other for either type or sub type and value will give the source table. But dictionary doesn't allow duplicate values here in type_id 3 ad 4 type is C

Comment: What operations need to be done on this data?  How will this data be used?

Comment: make sure you add the above comment to the question.  It will make your question more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use two classes?

Type would be main class with an subtype instance field (that can be null).

```
class Type
{

  public SubTypeClass SubType  {get; set;}

  public string Id {get;set;}

}
```

> I don't want to use class because I am
>   trying to make it configuratble. i.e.
>   we should be able to add a new column
>   in the type table and the application
>   should pickup the new column

I would recommend against this unless is a real need. Usually if a database table change that's for a really good reason and the application design should be reconsidered... if you have tables which can grow columns madly then your database design is probably not very good and surely not formalized (I assume standard SQL databases).

Take into account that, sub_type is not really a great definition and I assume you're using it as an example for a categorization... don't try to make a silver bullet data structure as you'll find out it brings more problems that it solves. With a good design changing one class if a given associated data table changes is not such a big deal as having a good for all class that barely works any better than direct SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit*:

Get the tuples of Type/Subtype/Source from the DB by using a query like:

```
SELECT table1.Type, table1.SubType, table2.Source from table1 JOIN table2 on table1.type_id = table2.type_id;
```

*End Edit*

Without knowing how the data is to be used, you could do the following:

```
class MyData{
    HashMap<String, String> columnData;
}
```

When inserting into columnData (which represents a single Type/SubType/Source tuple), it would be done like:

```
columnData.put("Type", type);
columnData.put("SubType", subtype);
columnData.put("Source", source);
```

This way, you do not need to change the class structure when new columns are added to the DB.

And then, in the main application, you could use:

```
List<MyData> list;
```

Of course, this answer could change depending on how this data will be used.

Comment: How can we map Type-Sub-Type-Source i.e. how can we find/retrieve the source based on the type and sub-type, sub-type can be null for most of the cases? The input to list is type and sub-type. and want to retrieve source?

Comment: Given that you said, in the question, that the Type_id is unavailable to the program, I would generate the Type/SubType/Source tuples by using a SQL query: SELECT table1.Type, table1.SubType, table2.Source from table1 JOIN table2 on table1.type_id = table2.type_id.  Then these tuples could be fed to the program.  Also, please put the fact that you want to find/retrieve Source based on Type/Subtype in the question.